# Solve the typescript - "No matches overload call" with ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes, use-ref

I am going to solve the typescript correspondent.
Here is the code and the error what I got.

```
const navRef = useRef<null | HTMLElement>(null);

const setFocusables = () => {
  let navCurrent = navRef.current || null;
  menuFocusables = [
    buttonRef.current,
    ...Array.from(navCurrent?.querySelectorAll('a')),
  ];
  firstFocusableEl = menuFocusables[0];
  lastFocusableEl = menuFocusables[menuFocusables.length - 1];
};
```

Here is the error what I got it now.

> let navCurrent: HTMLElement | null No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 4, '(iterable: Iterable |
> ArrayLike): HTMLAnchorElement[]', gave the
> following error.      Argument of type 'NodeListOf
> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Iterable | ArrayLike'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'Iterable | ArrayLike'.
> Overload 2 of 4, '(arrayLike: ArrayLike):
> HTMLAnchorElement[]', gave the following error.      Argument of type
> 'NodeListOf | undefined' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'ArrayLike'.        Type
> 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'ArrayLike'.ts(2769)

Please give me solution.
Thank you in advance.

Hi.

I hope to solve the above problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle when `navCurrent` is null, so it should be like:

```js
const navRef = useRef<null | HTMLElement>(null);

const setFocusables = () => {
  let navCurrent = navRef.current || null;
  menuFocusables = [
    buttonRef.current,
    // updated this
    ...Array.from(navCurrent?.querySelectorAll('a') ?? []),
  ];
  firstFocusableEl = menuFocusables[0];
  lastFocusableEl = menuFocusables[menuFocusables.length - 1];
};
```

Comment: Happy to help! Could you please mark as answered so people know it's resolved :)